# require_once : how to solve the "Warning with Fatal error"?

Tags: php

I cannot include the constants.php file.
I have the file directory,

```
-includes(Folder)
        -constants.php
```

But i cannot use this file in below the folder location,

```
- modules(Folder)
                - demo.php
```

It will throw the errors

**Warning:** require_once(../includes/constants.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\DBJN21\modules\demo.php on line 6
**Fatal error:** require_once(): Failed opening required '../includes/constants.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\DBJN21\modules\demo.php on line 6

**Sample code : modules/demo.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require_once "../includes/constants.php";

....
....

?>
```

Comment: try `require_once __DIR__ . '/../includes/constants.php';`

Comment: Hi YvesLeBorg, It's working fine. Lots of Thanks.